Fundamental group of Y(2)
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the upper half plane and $Y(2)=\mathcal{H}/\Gamma(2)$ as usual. The modular lambda function yields a bijection $Y(2)\xrightarrow{\sim}\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,1\}$. Let $a$ and $b$ small loops in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,1\}$ around the punctures 0 and 1 respectively. Then, by abuse of notations, $a$ and $b$ (freely) generate $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,1\})\simeq\Gamma(2)/\pm I$. Can we find the matrices in $\Gamma(2)$ corresponding to $a$ and $b$ respectively under the isomorphism $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,1\})\simeq\Gamma(2)/\pm I$?
